# Is naming minimized files with "min" necessary?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you know, the minimized version of files that include CSS, JS and etc. are also named as "xxx.min.js". For example "bootstrap.min.js".

Is it in any way significant or necessary to include ".min." in a minimized file name in terms of SEO or semantics? Or is it just a convention to be followed?

Comment: It has no technical purpose other than to make it easier for developers to recognize which version of the file is what without downloading/opening it.

Comment: The latter. And 3 letters ought to be enough for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a convention.

It stops you, the developer, from getting  your production and development files muddled.

If you provide your code as a download for other people to use, it makes it clear which version is which.